# Multi machine communication through Internet

Tags: ros, c++, ros-fuerte, multi-machine

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I have been using ROS for a while now and most of my activities involve multi-machine communication. However, all this happens in a network formed with a single router (LAN) in the same subnet.

My question is, is it possible to achieve multi-machine communication using ROS in a global scale? I believe it is definitely possible with complex TCP/IP programming or using the concept of server/ client. However, i would like to know are there any simpler techniques to achieve this the way I have been able to do simple multi-master communication using ROS in LAN.

It would be great if someone would be able walk me through the beginner's steps for this.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42503/multi-machine-communication-through-internet./) by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 612 on 2012-08-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would use a VPN. Have a look at [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/11045/how-to-set-up-vpn-between-ros-machines/?answer=16309#post-id-16309).

**Edit**: Maybe I should also provide some explanation.

As long as you set up your routing tables correctly, you can have nodes communicating across subnet boundaries. But it is important that nodes can directly reach each other, i.e. every computer needs to be pingable from every other computer. Theoretically, it would also be possible to create relay computers that relay nodes from one sub-net into another one but that's sort of hard to get right. The easiest solution for having multiple nodes in different subnets is definitely to set up a vpn and put all nodes into a virtual subnet.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on 2012-08-29**:
I did go through your link but it did not seem so simple for me the way its stated there coz am nt tht good on networking concepts. but it acts like a starter. Maybe I'll read more before i could post any sensible query on tht if i come across one. Thanks for your link and your answer there. :)

**Comment by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on 2012-09-03**:
I'll implement this answer at quiet a later time... but after my reading through several information on the internet your answer makes perfect sense now... vpn should definitely work. Thanks.